# Best practice for using jquery to interact with php classes?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a dropdown selector on a page that allows a user to select a template type (for example, "human" or "dog").

1. Based on what template is selected, different fields will need to populate below the dropdown (for example, text fields for "parents names" or a dropdown list for "breed") that are unique to each template.
2. I will have a button that the user will click once the data fields are put in that will output data to an "output div" section of the same page when clicked (no POSTing data as it's not being saved). The output will have different output logic based on the selected template (for example, "I'm a human named X" or "I'm a dog, my breed is Y").

My real program will be more complex and each template will have a php class that stores all of the logic. Since I will be dealing with both php objects and variables gathered by jquery, what's the best way to let them interact?

For 1., I know I can do something easy like -

```
var selected_template = $('#my-template-dropdown :selected').text();
if (selected_template == 'Human'){
                $('#my-fields').html('<?php echo HumanTemplate::render_fields(); ?>');
            }
```

which is easy enough, but for 2. I need to pass variables from jquery to php, then return output back to jquery.

I would like some advice on the easiest way to do this before I start down the wrong path.

Comment: are you intentionally avoiding ajax-action?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for responding to requests of advice! What's your specific question - e.g. "How do I do xyz? I've tried abc". Your question shows a lack of basic understanding of web programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

Allow the user to select the template type:

```
<form>
    <select id="my-template-dropdown" name='template'>
        <option value="dogs">Dogs</option>
        <option value="humans">Humans</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="my-fields"><div>
<div id="output"><div>
```

**jQuery**

Any time the user changes the template selection, request new content to display via AJAX, and insert it on the current page so the page does not have to refresh:

```
$('#my-template-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var template = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://your-site/path/to/' + template,
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#my-fields').html(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

`http://your-site/path/to/template` simply generates the HTML you want to display for that template, eg (just an example, don't know if this is suitable for your app):

```
if ($template == 'humans') {
    echo HumanTemplate::render_fields();
} else if ($template == 'dogs') {
    echo DogTemplate::render_fields();
}
```

For part 2, assuming all the logic you refer to is in the template rendered by PHP, you could then handle it with jQuery.  This is pretty crude, you probably need something more sophisticated (eg a full template  which you swap variables into?), but you get the idea:

```
$('#output').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // fields in your template which the user will fill
    var species = $('#species').val(),
        title = $('#title').val();
    // Probably better to have this text as a template in your source
    $('#output').html("I'm a " + species + ' named ' + title);
});
```

**NOTE** the gotcha in the event handler.  Event handlers will only attach to elements that exist at the time the handler is defined.  Since the content is injected after page load, an event handler like `$('#button).on('click', function() {...` would have no effect when clicking a button inserted via AJAX.  The syntax here attaches to the parent `#output` div, which *does* exist at page load, and filters for clicks on a button.  See the [jQuery event delegation docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more info.

Another option would be to POST the submitted data to some PHP controller, which generates and returns the output.  This way all your logic is in the one place.  For example, here the user's click will query the same PHP file which generated the initial template, this time including the values the user has entered.  It could then generate the required output and return it, to be inserted on the page.  You'd need to update the PHP so it can determine which of these cases it is handling (eg hidden field?); alternatively if you wanted to keep those separate you could hit another PHP file all together.

```
$('#output').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
    var template = $('#my-template-dropdown').val(),
        $form = $('form'),
        data = $form.serialize(); // Values from all fields user has entered
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://your-site/path/to/' + template,
        data: data,
        success: function(resp) {
            $('#output').html(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: For part 2, I would definitely need to pass data into a PHP function/class. The output would be completely different based on the template selected.

Is there a clean way to use PHP classes for this, rather than having to create another PHP file that would be something like "output.php" which would have to mix the human and dog logic? I'd like to stick to OOP principals and keep the logic separate between the templates.

Comment: OK - I've updated my answer with another example of how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to pass data from jQuery to PHP, is by using AJAX.
Mozilla has an excellent [guide on getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), that i recommend you follow.
An example of how you can achieve what you are requesting, is by trying the following:

```
var selected_template = $('#my-template-dropdown :selected').text();
var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
data =  {'select_template': selected_template };
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

On the PHP end (Ajax.php in my example) It could look something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['select_template'])) {
    // do something with the input from jQuery
    $selected_template = $_POST['select_template'];
    // return the result back to the client
    echo $seleted_template;
}

?>
```

$selected_template will be sent back to the client, and response in the AJAX function will be whatever the server returned. So the console.log(response) should display whatever was being sent to the server

Comment: This looks like it may work... so maybe the best way would be to make a "template_output_interface.php" which will be responsible for checking the `selected_template` variable and calling the associated PHP class. 

My only question left at this point is if I have to POST the data from Ajax, or is there another way to call a different, specific function from the "ajaxurl" file? I'll see if I can find the answer in the guide you posted, thanks.

Comment: Well yes, to get data from a client to a server, it needs to be posted in a way. Another way this can be achieved is by using $_GET.


By redirecting the user to an URL like this, you can get the "selected_template" 
example.com/ajaxurl.php?selected_template=$selected_template
Obviously the variable is whatever template the user selected.

To get what the was set as the "selected_template" you simply just do the following in the ajaxurl file:
$input = $_GET['selected_template'] and from there do your thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to the function [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

This function make available PHP datas to JS files on the page load through the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

This will not work like an Ajax request and only populate data for a specific handle on page load. But you can mix this method with ajax in the same script.

Hope it helps even it doesn't seems to fit to your case.

As your class not fires on page load, you can use the action [`wp_ajax_{custom _action}`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) and `wp_ajax_nopriv_{custom_action}` . For example, that's usually used to populate multiple dropdown, each time an event is trigger by the user, a php function returns result the js script.

Comment: This is interesting, I'm not sure I can use it since my class won't be selected when the page is loaded, though.

Using the example on that page, would I be able to call a PHP function and pass params? For example - 

    alert( object_name.my_function(some_var);

Comment: I added another thing to my answer